# PHP Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string?

Tags: php, loop

In my error log I m having this error:

> PHP Warning:  strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string

Which seems to make crash my server . . .

I'm not much aware of Server Conf / Back end Dev,  but this are the piece of code being impacted:

```
<?php
            # show categories 
            $categories = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'ev_categories', '<p>', ', ', '</p>' ); 
            $categories = strip_tags( $categories );
            echo $categories;
            if ($categories <> '') echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
        ?>

?php

# show categories 
$categories = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'ev_categories', '<p>', ', ', '</p>' ); 
$categories = strip_tags( $categories );

if ( strpos($categories,'arts and culture') !== false ) { $catID = 1; };
if ( strpos($categories,'business')         !== false ) { $catID = 2; };
if ( strpos($categories,'community')        !== false ) { $catID = 3; };
if ( strpos($categories,'education')        !== false ) { $catID = 4; };
if ( strpos($categories,'sport')            !== false ) { $catID = 5; };

?>

<?php

# show categories 
$categories = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'ev_categories', '<p>', ', ', '</p>' ); 
$categories = strip_tags( $categories );

if ( strpos($categories,'arts and culture') !== false ) { $catID = 1; };
if ( strpos($categories,'business')         !== false ) { $catID = 2; };
if ( strpos($categories,'community')        !== false ) { $catID = 3; };
if ( strpos($categories,'education')        !== false ) { $catID = 4; };
if ( strpos($categories,'sport')            !== false ) { $catID = 5; };

# show locations                    
$locations = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'ev_locations', '<p>', ', ', '</p>' ); 
$locations  = strip_tags( $locations  );
#echo $locations ;
```

?>

Each time, related to the second line below:

```
$categories = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'ev_categories', '<p>', ', ', '</p>' ); 
$categories = strip_tags( $categories );
```

If anybody is aware how I can fix this, it will be lovely,

Comment: Are you sure this is string? Maybe `get_the_term_list` returns false?

Comment: yes, this is the error inmy error log and the line it refers too :(

What do you mean by get_the_term_list ? Thank you :)

Comment: According to WP Codex `get_the_term_list` returns false if the post does not have any associated terms. In this case, when you assign it as a value to `$categories` it will be boolean `false`, not a `string`. Make sure that `get_the_term_list` returns string

Comment: Also try using `get_terms()` instead of `get_the_term_list()`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

Comment: There's no error handling!

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source of [`get_the_term_list`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_term_list/), you will see that it will try to get the terms first. If that doesn't succeed, it will return an error or `false`. So you would have to account for that before you try to strip the tags:

```
if (!is_wp_error ($categories) && false != $categories)
  $categories = strip_tags( $categories );
```

In all other cases `get_the_term_list` returns a string and your code should work fine.

By the way, it's not very useful to have `get_the_term_list` to add `<p>` tags if you strip those away immediately. Also, there is a filter towards the end of `get_the_term_list` that you could use to strip the link tags that are added by the function. Finally, you may want to take a look at [`get_the_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/), which will give you a nice array of terms without any tags to strip.

Comment: Im still having those error in the error log :(, I tried to change get_the_term_list by get_terms(), also to add your code suggested, but it s not changing anything unfortunatly. Do you know any other way by any chance ? Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Try var_dump on $categories to see what it looks like. That should help you track the bug down.

Answer (score 0):

???
$categories is an array, and it cant be parsed as string.
instead, you'd better to do this:

```
foreach($categories as $name =>$value){
   $locations[] = strip_tags($value->slug);
}
```

or another way for arrays

```
array_map('strip_tags', $categories);
```